# OLEDB extract Excel date format cell but result in incorrect outcome

Tags: c#, excel, date, oledb

I am trying to extract some data in an excel while I got an unexpected result.

I am publishing the project in IIS7.5 and use ACE as the engine to extract excel information, with this connection string:

```
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strNewPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1\""
```

My excel has some date fields like below:

[Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ekjQ.jpg)

When I use the below code to extract data:

```
    query = "select * from [Roster$]";

    cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

    da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    da.Fill(ds);

    ShowMessage(ds.Tables[0].Rows[10][0].ToString());
```

I got the interesting result as below:

```
    1-¤Q¤@¤ë
```

while I am expecting this:

```
    1-Nov
```

Do anyone have idea on what is happening to my engine? I tried all kind of browsers but got negative result. Meanwhile, it gives what I want if I do not publish to IIS, but access through debug mode in visual studio.

Will thank to everyone helping me!

Answer (score 0):

use this connString,

```
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strNewPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;\""
```

working fine....

Answer (score 0):

Check the number format in excel or share your sample  excel sheet here

Comment: The number format of the date cell is Custom: d-mmm. 
When I use other formats like m/d/yyyy, it works fine. I guess there is something wrong with the minus "-" sign

Comment: in debug mode check the value appear in ds.